# How do I get the second table class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a table in a Wikipedia page using BeautifulSoup. I know how to get the first table, but how do I get the second table (Recent changes to the list of S&P 500 Components) with the same class `wikitable sortable`?

my code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
r=requests.get(url)
url=r.content
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url,'html.parser')

tab = soup.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"})
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `soup.find_all` and access the last table. Since there are only two `table` tags with `wikitable sortable` as its class, the last element in the resulting list will be the "Recent Changes" table:

```
soup.find_all("table", {"class":"wikitable sortable"})[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an nth-of-type css selector to specify the second matching table

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
r = requests.get(url)
url = r.content
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')

tab = soup.select_one("table.wikitable.sortable:nth-of-type(2)")
print(tab)
```